# Apache Airflow -- How to Specify Unix User when Using BashOperator

Tags: python, apache-spark, airflow

Currently, my team is testing out Airflow for creating workflows of Spark jobs. We are using Airflow version 1.8.0. We have an Airflow web server running on a remote machine that all of us have SSH access to. Another team member is the one who started the web server from his own prompt, therefore the process shows as running under his username.

I've created my own DAG to be run by the server, essentially just a serial workflow of spark-submit commands using the BashOperator. When I run these jobs via the web interface, they are submitted correctly and I can track them via the HUE job browser for our cluster. **The problem is that they are not listed as submitted by my username, they are listed as submitted by the username of the team member who is running the Airflow web server.**

Is there any way to specify which user the BashOperator to operate as? Or is there a best practice stating how best to handle all BashOperator tasks being submitted by a single user?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**

It looks like this may be a gap in functionality as described by [Airflow-357](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-357?jql=status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20text%20~%20%22BashOperator%22)... but I'd still like to know if there's a work-around or method/parameter that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'run_as_user': '' in default_args of DAG definition.

This will make a sudo -c  when it will launch the BashOperator